# How can we construct algorithm to evaluate logarithm of a real positive number

Tags: algorithm-analysis, logic

How can we construct the algorithm to evaluate the logarithm of a real positive number bit by bit in the base 2 system?
I have first expressed any number as $x\cdot2^n$, where $x \in [1,2]$, by shifting the binary points. But after that, I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Here is a starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Calculation

Comment: you can also have $x$ belong to interval $[1,2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $x$ with $1 \le x < 2$. We need to find $f = \log x$ (log base is 2). Denote the binary form of $f$ as $(0.b_1 b_2 b_3 \ldots)$ . Each $b_i$ is a bit.

$f = \log x \quad\quad (1)$

$\Leftrightarrow$
$2f = \log x^2$

$\Leftrightarrow$
$(b_1. b_2 b_3 \ldots) = \log x^2$

So, $x^2 \ge 2$ implies $b_1$ must be $1$, and $x^2 < 2$ implies $b_1$ must be $0$.  Thus, $b_1$ can be deduced just by comparing $x^2$ with $2$.

After finding $b_1$, subtract it from both sides of above to obtain equation similar to $(1)$. Repeat the process to deduce bit $b_2$. Repeat this to deduce as many bits as required.

You can read further about this algorithm in this [article](https://mathsanew.com/articles/computing_logarithm_bit_by_bit.pdf) (written by me).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @Nitin Verma.